# Web server choice for SSJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, ssjs

We are currently in process of development web application with SSJS. Which web server is thought to be most optimal to use with SSJS and why? Is there any documentation available?

Comment: It's interesting that you could have made the decision to write server code in JavaScript without having found candidate answers to the question for feature comparison with other server technologies.

Comment: SSJS implementations tend to depend on APIs that are quite tightly bound to specific web servers … so it is hard to see how you could have started development before picking a server. Shopping questions are off-topic for SO anyway.

Comment: @Pointy I completely agree. This is a type of question that should be answered before making any decisions about components of the development infrastructure.

Comment: @Pointy BUT in our case we could allow ourselves of such "luxury" for several reasons: 
1. We had some experience with Apache web server and it seemed more than suitable for our needs.
2. Web application that we are developing is done in such a way that it can be easily translated to other servers.
3. After research we have discovered that the configuration: "Apache web server + SSJS" have been used by other developers successfully.
4. With configuration "Apache web server + SSJS" you can have all features of Apache Web server and SSJS combined.

Comment: @Quentin I should have mentioned in my question that we are using NodeJS as SSJS server: as we found out nodejs is commonly used one.

Comment: So use Node. Unless you are asking what makes a good proxy server. But that's still a shopping question and is off-topic.